# Tablesorter : TypeError: c is undefined :::: c.page++;

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, tablesorter

Hi i am using tablesorter [Link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) .. and my pagination is not working if i include " page_my(_($help_context = "Table")); " --- which is my header section

*header section : basically include HTML tags and session value* ... i taught because of my session and  php code may be causing not to run pagination , hence  i removed all php and session code .. but still it not working ... also there is no other JS file include in this

Below is my code

```
<?php  

$page_security = 'SA_TABLESORTER';
$path_to_root = "..";

include($path_to_root . "/includes/session.inc");

page_my(_($help_context = "Table"));


        echo'

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="table/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />

        <script src="table/jquery-latest.js"></script>       
        <script src="table/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <script src="table/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="table/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { 

        $("table").tablesorter({ 
        widthFixed: true, widgets: ["zebra", "filter"], 

        headers: { 5: { sorter: false, filter: false } }, 

        widgetOptions : { 

        filter_cssFilter : \'tablesorter-filter\', 

        filter_childRows : false, 


        filter_startsWith : false 

        } 

        })
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})  ;
        });

        </script>';



?>


 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Web Site</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
</tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Student01</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td> 
        </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Student02</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Smith2</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Doe1q</td>
    <td>Jason</td>
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
</tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>Student03</td>
            <td>Languages3</td>
            <td>male3</td>
            <td>180</td> 
        </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Mathematics4</td>
            <td>male4</td>
            <td>190</td>
        </tr>


</tbody>
</table>


<?php

echo"<div id=\"pager\" class=\"pager\">
    <br \>
    <form>
        <img src=\"table/first.png\" class=\"first\"/>
        <img src=\"table/prev.png\" class=\"prev\"/>
        <input type=\"text\" class=\"pagedisplay\"/>
        <img src=\"table//next.png\" class=\"next\"/>
        <img src=\"table/last.png\" class=\"last\"/>
        <select class=\"pagesize\">
            <option selected=\"selected\"  value=\"10\">10</option>
            <option value=\"20\">20</option>
            <option value=\"30\">30</option>
            <option  value=\"40\">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>"; 
?>



<?php
br(1);
end_page();  // footer section
?>
```

If i remove " page_my(_($help_context = "Table")); " - this function then my pagination works fine but if i include this function ( which my header section ) then i am getting **error in firebug**

> TypeError: c is undefined
>
> c.page++;   at link 46 of " jquery.tablesorter.pager.js "

which is :

```
function moveToNextPage(table) { 
            var c = table.config;
            c.page++;
            if(c.page >= (c.totalPages-1)) {
                c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
            }
            moveToPage(table);
}
```

Comment: The error means there is no property 'page' in table.config variable.. why don't you use a better Table sort plugin like http://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: Hey Bhavesh , thanks for reply .. dude but as i said .. when i remove " page_my(_($help_context = "Table")); " then also works fine .. and this function has all my HEADER SECTION contents

Comment: bhavesh : +1 for datatables link.. thanks

Comment: any one here ... still waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder what version of tablesorter you are using. The link you shared was to the original tablesorter v2.0.5b.

The filter widget is part of my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), which requires the version of the plugin and pager which is downloaded from GitHub. It appears that you are using the correct files, but please verify the version numbers. The fork is currently at 2.17.4.

Edit: Actually the pager code you shared doesn't look anything at all like the current code:

```
moveToNextPage = function(table, p) {
    p.page++;
    if ( p.page >= ( Math.min( p.totalPages, p.filteredPages ) - 1 ) ) {
        p.page = ( Math.min( p.totalPages, p.filteredPages ) - 1 );
    }
    moveToPage(table, p);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, i have used tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.zip  .. can you please share me exact link for downloading latest file ?

Comment: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/ click on the version number at the top of the page, or scroll to the bottom of the page to see a "zip" and "tar.gz" download buttons